# Epistemic vs. ontological interpretations of QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, quantum-interpretations, foundations

There are several posts under   ***[quantum-interpretations] epistemic ontological***,   but I'm not seeing an answer to my question there (nor from google searches)...

I hadn't thought about it very much, but I'd always thought it's simply that   **mixtures are epistemic**   whereas   **superpositions are ontological**.   So it's not really a matter of **interpretation**, just a matter of **preparation**.

But there's so much discussion about epistemic/ontological that this must be way too naive an understanding (or a complete misunderstanding). So how is it that epistemic/ontological is more foundational than just mixture/superposition? Are there any related arXiv (or other) articles?

Comment: What precisely is the question?

Comment: "superpositions are ontological" -- I think by saying this you've chosen a side. The underlying question is whether quantum superpositions are ontological (represent a state of nature) or epistemic (represent our state of knowledge of nature).

Comment: Related: [What are the differences between a $\psi$-epistemic ontological model and a $\psi$-ontic model of quantum mechanics, exactly?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290522/what-are-the-differences-between-a-psi-epistemic-ontological-model-and-a-ps/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not consider mixed states produced by a partial trace, since I do not think you are intersted in this case.

Consider $N= N_1+N_2$ copies of a given physical system. The first $N_1$ are prepared in the pure state $\psi_1$, the remaining $N_2$ are prepared in the pure stste $\psi_2$. Now mix the systems, e.g. for photons, collect all photons, simultaneously,  in a given circuit.
The mixed state representing the ensemble is
$$\rho:= p_1 |\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_1| + p_2 |\psi_2\rangle \langle \psi_2|  \tag{1}$$
where $$p_i:= N_i/N\:,\quad i= 1,2\:.$$
Suppose that $\langle \psi_1|\psi_2\rangle \neq 0$.
Since $\rho$ is selfadjoint, it can be decomposed along the basis of its eigenvectors
$$\rho = \sum_j q_j |\phi_j\rangle \langle \phi_j|\:.\tag{2}$$
This new decomposition **cannot** coincide with the previous one because here $\langle\phi_i|\phi_j\rangle =0$ if $i\neq j$.
In principle, we can prepare the ensemble by mixing the pure states $\phi_i$ with the weights $q_i$. So also (2) is a possible practical way to produce the final mixed state $\rho$

Once the mixture has been created. All possible information we can experimentally  get from the ensemble is of the form $tr(\rho P)$, where $P$ is any test on the system (orthogonal projector).
So, there is no way to decide how the system was prepared: if according to (1) or (2).

In view of this fact it is difficult to argue that mixed states (prepared as above by a direct simultaneous mixing in a given region of space) are epistemic and pure states are ontic.

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [Classical and quantum probabilities in density matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/98703/classical-and-quantum-probabilities-in-density-matrices).