# Difference in density matrix where prob. 1/2 in both $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

In my course, we had an example: give the density matrix of a system arising from a proces that generates a [0> with probability 1/2 and a [1> with prob. 1/2. The answer is
$1/2[0\rangle\langle0] +1/2[1\rangle\langle1]$.

But it seems to me that $\sqrt{1/2}[0\rangle + \sqrt{1/2}[1\rangle$ does the same, which has a different density function, $1/2[0\rangle\langle0]+1/2[1\rangle\langle0]+1/2[0\rangle\langle1]+1/2[1\rangle\langle1]$. What is my mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is a quantum superposition different from a mixed state?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80434/)

Comment: No, probably I don't see it. Those answers are too general and difficult. Let's stick to this example.

Comment: But what do you mean with "this example" - you're asking about the difference between the density matrix and a wave function. This is exactly what the linked post deals with, i.e. it explains the difference between the superposition and density matrices. Actually, the answers, as far as I see, also deal with two state systems, which corresponds to your example. In general, for mixed states, there is no single wave function yielding this density matrix.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens if you measure either of the two states in the {|+>,|->} basis, and see which of the two matches what you expect from that process.

Comment: The question *is* a duplicate and in fact deals with the same example as the duplicate.  Any answers to your question would do as well for the linked duplicate.  If you want a hint, try a superposition with complex coefficients.