# Example of mixd entangled state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I'm looking for specific examples of all combinations of pure, mixed, separable and entangled states, but I would prefer if they all have some physical significance.

For pure states, the separable ones are the vector states, they are pretty basic and for entangled pure states I thought of the Bell states.

However, I'm having trouble finding examples of mixed states, both separable and entangled, which are simple enough, but aren't completely arbitrarily constructed.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at these: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1365/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80434/

Comment: I'm closing this as essentially a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70436/2451. Asking for examples is _too broad_ in the sense that the answer is non-unique, which tends to fit the SE Q&A format poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Just mix the pure state examples you have.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/246294)

Comment: @CosmasZachos Why does it not provide an answer to the question?

Comment: It is a brief hint, normally reserved for a brief comment. While I cannot second-guess  the OP's confusion, I doubt this hint dispels it. Please contrast to the friendlier answer of the duplicate question.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Answers in comments are discouraged, so I recently started to put such comments which are in fact answers into answers.  I understand this is encouraged by the mods.

Comment: We may be circling the drain of quibbles. I think @Luboš Motl 's answer does not belong to comments, but your hint does. I could visualize the OP asking further clarifications in the comments, in which case you could provide a less tautological answer going to the heart of his confusion and satisfying him. But this has a whiff of meta, doesn't it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos My feeling is more that it has a whiff of "is there actually a question".

Comment: In that case, sibylline question criticism quips resoundingly belong to the comments, not the question fields.