# Need help understanding weird definition of pure states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, density-operator, quantum-states

So in many sources I have read that

```
A pure state contains only one element, since the only entry on the 
density matrix will be 1.
```

But what about superpositions?

I mean a state like

$$\mid \psi\rangle = \alpha\mid0\rangle+\beta\mid1\rangle$$

for example is a pure state but it's corresponding density matrix can have 4 non-zero elements.

Why is it that these definitions seem to ignore superpositions?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70436/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Hint : Rank of density matrix of a pure state is 1.