# How to find the density operator of two joint systems given the density operator of the individual systems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, mathematics, density-operator

If I have two systems A and B and I want to find the density operator of the joint systems $\rho_{AB}$, is it just the tensor product of the density matrix of the individual systems, $\rho_{AB} = \rho_A\otimes\rho_B$? If not, what am I neglecting? (Maybe information about the correlation of the two system is lost)

Comment: The existing answer is good. For a concrete counterexample: consider a system of two qubits, each having reduced density matrix $\rho_R=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&\\&1/2\end{pmatrix}$ (like a classical coin flip). The joint state *might* be $\rho=\rho_R\otimes\rho_R=\begin{pmatrix}1/4&&&\\&1/4&&\\&&1/4&\\&&&1/4\end{pmatrix}$ (like two independent coin flips), or it might be $\rho=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\begin{pmatrix}1/2&&&\\&0&&\\&&0&\\&&&1/2\end{pmatrix},$ where the qubits are in the pure (and entangled) state $|\psi\rangle=\frac1{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle).$ Or something in between.

Comment: @HTNW This basically is the example I mention in the first link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible in general, as both density matrices could be the reduced density matrices of several joint density operators, see e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/688560/does-a-subsystem-being-mixed-imply-the-state-is-entangled) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714482/when-is-rho-ab-rho-a-otimes-rho-b-true).

The reduced density matrices determine the joint (bipartite) density operator uniquely if and only if at least one of these two density matrices is pure.

---

Indeed, consider a bipartite density matrix $\rho$ and suppose that at least one of its reduced density matrices $\rho_A$ is pure. Owing to the convex nature of the space of density matrices/their spectral properties, we can always write
$$\rho=\sum\limits_{k} p_k |\psi_k\rangle\langle \psi_k|  \tag 1 \quad , $$

which shows that

$$\rho_A=\mathrm{Tr}_B  \rho = \sum\limits_k p_k \mathrm{Tr}_B  |\psi_k\rangle\langle \psi_k| = \sum\limits_k p_k \rho_{A,k}\tag 2 \quad .$$

But if $\rho_A$ is pure, then $(2)$ implies that $\rho_A=\rho_{A,k}$ for all $k$, due to the extremal properties of the pure states. The Schmidt decompositions of the $|\psi_k\rangle$'s now show that $$|\psi_k\rangle\langle \psi_k| = \rho_{A,k} \otimes \rho_{B,k} = \rho_A\otimes \rho_{B,k} \tag 3 $$

which then gives

$$\rho=\rho_A\otimes \rho_B  \tag{4}\quad , $$
with $\displaystyle \rho_B=\sum\limits_k p_k \,\rho_{B,k}$.

Note that $\rho$ can be mixed, which is the case if and only if $\rho_B$ is mixed. Thus, if you have two density matrices $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$, and at least one is pure, then the joint density matrix is necessarily of the form $(4)$ and thus uniquely specified.

Conversely, if both $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are mixed, there are uncountably many different density matrices $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ with $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ as reduced density matrices, which shows that in this case the joint density operator is not uniquely specified. The first link above contains some explicit example.

For a proof of this fact, see e.g. *Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics. John von Neumann. New Edition. Princeton University Press. Chapter 2, p. 276-78.*