# What is the intuition behind density matrix?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, density-operator, quantum-states

What gives density matrix the expressive power to be able to represent mixture of pure states?

For example if $|\Omega\rangle$ is 50-50 mixture of $|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u\rangle+|d\rangle)$ and $|\Phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|u\rangle-|d\rangle)$ we can not represent such as $|\Omega\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|\Psi\rangle+|\Phi\rangle)$, but we can represent it as $\rho=\frac{1}{2}(|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|+|\Phi\rangle\langle\Phi|)$.

Intuitively what makes $|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ able to represent such as opposed to $|\Psi\rangle$?

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121337/50583 and its linked questions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way you can think of it - we will specialize to a finite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ for simplicity.  Abstractly, the *state* of a quantum system should be identified with a probability distribution for every possible measurement one could make.

A given self-adjoint operator $A$ can be expanded as $A=\sum_i \lambda_i \Pi_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue and $\Pi_i$ the orthogonal projection operator onto the $i^{th}$ eigenspace.  With this in mind, a *ray* $\boldsymbol \Psi$ in the underlying Hilbert space defines a probability distribution as follows. Pick any vector $\psi$ from that ray; then the probability of measuring $A$ to have value $\lambda_i$ is simply
$$\frac{\langle \psi, \Pi_i \psi\rangle}{\langle\psi,\psi\rangle}$$

With this as motivation, we define an *event* as an orthogonal projector $\Pi$, and the probability of that event to be
$$P_\Psi(\Pi):= \frac{\langle \psi,\Pi \psi\rangle}{\langle \psi,\psi\rangle} \in [0,1]$$

In that sense, $P_\Psi$ constitutes a probability measure on the set $\mathcal P(\mathcal H)$ of orthogonal projection operators. We now ask whether it is the most general form of probability measure; this question is answered in the negative by [Gleason's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleason%27s_theorem), which says that the set of all probability measures is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of positive-semidefinite, self-adjoint operators $\rho$ with $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho)=1$ (i.e. density operators), with the corresponding probability measure being given by $\Pi \mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(\Pi \rho)$. The probability measures which arise from rays in $\mathcal H$ - which correspond to so-called *pure states* - form a strict subset of all probability measures.

---

The proof of Gleason's theorem is technical and beyond the scope of a PSE answer in my opinion. However, it is useful to see how the set of pure states is insufficient.  Consider $\mathcal H= \mathbb C^2$ - does there exist a state of the system whose probability measure is uniform, such that for any observable $A$ with two distinct outcomes (eigenvalues) the probability of each is 1/2?

If we restrict ourselves to pure states, then the answer is no which can be seen easily.  Consider $P_\Psi$ for some arbitrary ray $\Psi$, let $\psi$ be a normalized vector in that ray, and let $\phi$ be a normalized vector in the orthogonal complement of $\Psi$.  Then $\{|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|,|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|\}$ is a set of orthogonal projectors which sum to the identity, yet $P_\Psi(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|)=1\neq 1/2$ and $P_\Psi(|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|) = 0\neq 1/2$.

As a result, if we want to generalize to allow for such statistical ensembles, we must enlarge the state space from the set of rays in $\mathcal H$ to the set of density operators on $\mathcal H$. It's not hard to show that the latter objects can be written $\rho = \sum_i p_i |\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$ where $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and $\{\psi_i\}$ is some collection of unit vectors in $\mathcal H$.

Answer (score 4):

$|\Omega\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\Psi\rangle+|\Phi\rangle)$ is a *superposition* state, but it's a state on its own and will evolve accordingly. If it described a system undergoing two-slit diffraction, with $|\Psi\rangle$ being the wavefunction of one slit and $|\Phi\rangle$ that of the other one, the evolution of $|\Omega\rangle$ would give you the two-slit interference pattern, because *both* slits are contributing. The particle goes through both slits, since it's a superposition.

$\rho=\frac{1}{2}(|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|+|\Phi\rangle\langle\Phi|)$ is a statistical mixture, meaning that the system is *either* in $|\Psi\rangle$ *or* in $|\Phi\rangle$. That is you *know* that the particle has gone through *one* of the two slits, you just don't know which one. The density matrix allows to evolve the two states at the same time, but each of them is evolving as a single state, not as a superposition.

Comment: $\vert \Omega\rangle$ is not suitably normalized as a superposition…

Comment: @superciocia Thanks for your answer. But again what makes $|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$ being able to have those properties you mentioned as opposed to $|\Psi\rangle$? What makes it so that we can evolve it in parallel to another state?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Fixed, added factor of $1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @alpal $|\Psi\rangle\langle \Psi|$ is just a matrix constructed out of $|\Psi\rangle$. The *sum* of those two matrices makes sure that $\rho$ is diagonal in the basis $(\Phi, \Psi)$, so that they can't affect each other (like they would do in a superposition.

Comment: @superciocia Right, but what I don't get is how one can come up with the idea that if we take the outer product of $|\Psi\rangle$ the resulting matrix would still represent and encode the same thing as $|\Psi\rangle$? Not that this new matrix represents such but also we can linearly add other states outer product into it as well as their corresponding classical probabilities!